# Google CSE (Custom Search Engine) - How to determine term user searched for (using jQuery)?

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search

I have a Google CSE embedded using this:

```
google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en', style : google.loader.themes.SHINY});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
var options = {};
options[google.search.Search.RESTRICT_EXTENDED_ARGS] = {'sort': 'date'};
var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('',options);
customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
customSearchControl.draw('cse');
```

I'd like to determine/display the search term the user searches for, but I can't seem to get the search term out of the Google CSE input after the user clicks "search".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This should get it:

```
var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('your key');
customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);

// add this    
customSearchControl.setSearchStartingCallback(this,
        function(sc, searcher, query) {
            alert(query);
            // or do whatever you want with it here.
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt the search terms be available in the header that is returned, I'm wondering if you cant get access to the actual ajax request and then use jquery to access the header object.  I know when doing a regular search on google the keywords are passed along in the header.

Comment: I'm quite a n00b, so my answer will be limited, but:

I did a search and got the results.  I used Firebug to look at the page source.  I didn't find my search term anywhere.  Does this relate to your comment?

Comment: it would be in the header data coming back from the ajax request